# Is it possible to have select event listener automatically called before Primefaces Treenode context menus are displayed?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a Treenode which has "select" listener:

```
<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{treeManagedBean.nodeSelectListener}"></p:ajax>
```

and context menus:

```
<p:contextMenu for="tree1" nodeType="nodeType1">
    <p:menuitem value="menu 1" actionListener="#{treeManagedBean.menu1ActionListener}"/>
    <p:menuitem value="menu 2" actionListener="#{treeManagedBean.menu2ActionListener}"/>
</p:contextMenu>
```

"nodeSelectListener" is correctly called when a node is selected by clicking left mouse button  and also context menus are displayed when right mouse button is clicked on a node.

The problem I am having is that a user can right click on a node before selecting it which means context menus are displayed but "nodeSelectListener" is not called. Is there anyway to have "nodeSelectListener" called when the user clicks with right mouse button but before context menus are displayed?

Comment: try adding this aditional p:ajax `<p:ajax event="contextMenu" listener="#{treeManagedBean.nodeSelectListener}"></p:ajax>`

Comment: This has worked perfectly. Thanks for your help. I have  a related question which you might be able to help. Is it possible to have "nodeSelectListener" invoked when i call node.setSelected(true) from backing bean? At the moment when I call node.setSelected(true), "node" is selected but "nodeSelectListener" is not called.